# How to use assets files that are outside the javascripts and stylesheets directory in grails?

Tags: grails

I would like to use third-party libraries in a grails project.

In order to use a third-party library, I have to copy the css and javascript files of the third-party library to the stylesheets and javascripts directories in the assets of grails-app respectively because as far as I understand that the Grails framework requires css and javascript files to be in the stylesheets and javascripts directories in the assets of grails-app respectively.

Then, they should be linked in the following way in a view/gsp file. For example:

```
<asset:stylesheet href="application.css"/>
<asset:stylesheet href="main.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

My question is, **is there any way to link assets files that are outside the javascripts and stylesheets directory in grails?**

For instance:

**How can I link the css/style.css file in a view/gsp file?**

An example project structure:

```
grails-app
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   │       style.css
│   ├───images
│   │       favicon.ico
│   │       grails.svg
│   │       spinner.gif
│   ├───javascripts
│   │       application.js
│   │       bootstrap.js
│   │       jquery-3.3.1.min.js
│   └───stylesheets
│           application.css
│           bootstrap.css
│           grails.css
│           main.css
├───conf
├───controllers
├───domain
├───i18n
├───init
├───services
├───taglib
├───utils
└───views
```

Or should I use the [external](https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/ref/Tags/external.html) tag after installed the [Resources plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/resources)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create `themes` directory in the assets.
Then static assets will be called in the following way.

```
<asset:stylesheet href="test.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="test.js"/>
<asset:stylesheet href="admin/test.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="admin/test.js"/>
```

A project structure looks like the following:

```
grails-app
├───assets
│   ├───images
│   │       favicon.ico
│   │       grails.svg
│   │       spinner.gif
│   │
│   ├───javascripts
│   │       application.js
│   │       bootstrap.js
│   │       jquery-3.3.1.min.js
│   │
│   ├───stylesheets
│   │       application.css
│   │       bootstrap.css
│   │       grails.css
│   │       main.css
│   │
│   └───themes
│       ├───admin
│       │   ├───css
│       │   │       test.css
│       │   │
│       │   └───js
│       │           test.js
│       │
│       ├───css
│       │       test.css
│       │
│       └───js
│               test.js
│
├───conf
├───controllers
...
```